# SQL check if record exists in table before bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, bulkinsert

I currently have a stored procedure that performs bulk insert into a table named "TomorrowPatients" from a .csv file. When performing the bulk insert, I need to determine if the record being added already exists within the table and if so DO NOT add the record. If the record does not exist then I need to APPEND it to the table. What is the most efficient way to go about this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I have created a temp table called "TomorrowPatients_Temp". I am trying to use this table to determine which records to insert.

Comment: I would say BULK IMPORT into a temp table and then do an INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS or a MERGE

Comment: Bulk insert into temp / staging table and then left join it to a destination table with `where destination.PK is null`

Comment: Could you provide an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your the whole data into a temporary table, say #TempData.Then use the following code :

```
INSERT INTO TommorowPatients
SELECT * FROM #TempTable TT
LEFT JOIN TommorowPatients TP ON TT.PatientId = TP.PatienId
    AND TT.PatientName = TP.PatientName
    AND TT.PatientSSN = TP.PatientSSN
WHERE TP.PatientId IS  NULL
```

Where PatientId is you primary key for the TommorowPatients table.

DO NOT add the "RoomNumber" column with the LEFT JOIN like : TT.RoomNo = TP.RoomNo. This way even if the room number changes, new data won't be inserted as we have joined only based on patient specific data.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying this right now. Will let you know how it goes

Comment: Will this work even if the data has changed in the non-temporary table. After the initial load of data the user can manipulate what 'Room' the record is in and this will mean it will NOT be the exact same row in the temp as in the non-temp tables

Comment: By "non temporary tables" , do you mean the table you are inserting into ? That is, the "MyTable" I have used in my answer ?

Comment: I have two tables: "TomorrowPatients" & "TomorrowPatients_Temp". In the morning, we have a script that populates the TomorrowPatients table. After this population, the user can specify a "roomnumber" for each patient. When the user does this, the roomnumber is saved in the tomorrowpatients table. During the day, more patients may be added. If we run the same procedure we already have then the table will be cleared and we will lose all the specified "roomnumbers". We need to be able to run something that will simply append the data to the table if there is a "new" patient and do nothing if not.

Comment: In that case, apply LEFT JOIN only on Patient specific Columns, not on the room number column. I will try to update my answer based on this. And I suppose you can update you question with the data you just provided me.

Comment: I am getting error: "Invalid Object Name '#TempTable'. Also, I do not understand the logical flow of how this works and when I will need to run this.

Comment: You have to create the temp table like you create a normal table and then insert values into the table.

Comment: I'm getting another error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" -- both tables have all the same columns and the exact same datatypes. What could this mean?